# How to parse %2C as a comma in CORS XMLHttpRequest Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, xmlhttprequest

Is there a way to provide a custom, response header parser to the XMLHttpRequest for CORS requests?  I'm trying to make a CORS request with jQuery and believe the receiving service has a bug in the way it returns the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.  All the allowed headers are separated by commas save the last two, which are separated by an escaped comma, %2C.  This causes my XMLHttpRequest to raise the following exception (pay no attention to the source or destination addresses, or the X-FOO header because they are substitutes for the actual values):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://service.example.com/activity' from origin 'http://client.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field X-FOO is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Here is the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header from the preflight response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Accept,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,content-type%2Cx-foo
```

I don't have access to the destination service, is there a way I may tell the XMLHttpRequest to parse %2C as a normal comma in the preflight response headers?  My jQuery request looks like the following:

```
$.ajax({
    method: method,
    url: `${endpoint}/${activity}`,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        "X-FOO": token
    },
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to provide a custom, response header parser to the XMLHttpRequest for CORS requests?

No.

If there was then you could write one which allowed whatever header you liked.

Comment: There are other clients interacting with the server via webapps, that do not have this problem.  Even Curl seems to parse %2C as a comma.  It's really strange ...

Comment: CURL isn't subject to CORS permissions - these other "webapps" as you call them may be performing the request via their own server - again, not subject to CORS

Comment: Only web browsers implement the same origin policy (and thus CORS, which is a technology that can relax the SOP), so a curl client wouldn't be parsing the `Access-Control-Allow-Header` header in the first place.

Comment: Curl wouldn't even be preglighting to begin with @Quentin

Comment: It has been brought to my attention that the other clients run as web assemblies (WebGL apps).  Are web assemblies subject to CORS?

Comment: What I need to understand is how the other clients are able to work while mine fails.